# If the determinant of an real orthogonal matrix $Q$ is 1, prove that there exists a real skew-symmetric $K$ such that $Q=e^K$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

> If the determinant of an real orthogonal matrix $Q$ is 1, prove that there exists a real skew-symmetric $K$ such that $Q=e^K$.

Every complex orthogonal matrix $Q$ can be represented in the form
$$Q=Re^{iK}$$
where $R$ is real orthogonal matrix and $K$ a real skew-symmetric matrix.
Should I use that theorem to prove it?

Comment: Your result on complex-orthogonal matrices seems a bit too strong of a result to use here.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows: first, note (or show as a consequence of the spectral theorem for normal matrices) that if $Q$ is a real orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $Q = PDP^{T}$, where $D$ is the block diagonal matrix with blocks $D_1,\dots,D_k$ where
$$
D_j = \pmatrix{a_j & -b_j\\b_j & a_j}, \quad 1 \leq j \leq k
$$
for some real numbers $a_j,b_j$.

Now, find a skew-symmetric matrix $K_j$ such that $e^{K_j} = D_j$.  Define $K$ to be the block diagonal matrix with blocks $K_1,\dots,K_k$.  Finally, note that
$$
\exp[PKP^T] = P\exp(K)P^T = PDP^T = Q
$$
and that $PKP^T$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: So the use of the determinant 1 is that $D_j$ is skew-symmetric, am i correct? But why?

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN $D_j$ is not skew symmetric.  The fact that $Q$ has determinant $1$ tells us that it is orthogonally similar to a "diagonal sum" of rotations.  Otherwise, $Q$ also involves a reflection and therefore has an eigenvalue of $-1$.

Comment: Ahh sorry, i used to work with complex matrix so i am mixed up with conjugate transpose. I am still not familiar with rotation matrix. What if $Q$´s size is $2 \times 2$?

Comment: Is this $K$ unique? Since exponential function is monotonically increasing, for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, if $e^a=e^b$ then $a=b$. But how about matrix?

Comment: For your first comment, I don’t understand why anything should be different in the case that $Q$ has size 2, and I don’t know what you mean by “I am not familiar with rotation matrix”. For your second comment, $K$ is not unique.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've already understand for my first comment.